# Layer preview using OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I have been using GeoServer from quite sometime now and publishing layers and consuming services. Recently I have started facing the issue mentioned below when I am trying to preview the layer in GeoServer using OpenLayers, but renders the layer using GeoJSON. I am unable to resolve this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://x.x.x.x:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException code="ForbiddenFormat">
      Creating maps using application/openlayers is not allowed
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Comment: it looks like you changed the permissions of formats available and prevented access to the openlayers format.

Comment: I don't know. Layers in few workspaces work properly except for newly added workspaces. From where can i set the permissions ?